# Timestamp returning wrong date and also getting Parse Exceptions

Tags: java, android, firebase, timestamp

I'm writing a method now to get the `timestamp` difference between when the post was uploaded to Firebase and Today's Date / Time. Based on a video I've watched and other posts on here, this is the method `getTimeDate` I have come up with. I pass it to my `ViewHolder`, although I am getting an `E/: getTimeDate: ParseException: Unparseable date: "1576534039437"`, and also `E/: getTimeDate: ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Dec 16 23:07:19 GMT+01:00 2019"`. Thought it was good, but it's just returning **today**.

Can someone tell me what I have wrong in my code? Legit can't figure out what I have wrong and I'm pretty sure it's close to right.

The objective is for the `TextView` to say something like 6 hours ago, 32 minutes ago, 4 days ago, etc.

**PostAdapter.java**

```
if ("".equals(post.getTimestamp())) {
            holder.timestamp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            if (post.getPostid() != null) {
                holder.timestamp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String timestampDifference = getTimeDate();
                if (!timestampDifference.equals("0")) {
                    holder.timestamp.setText(timestampDifference + " days ago");
                } else {
                    holder.timestamp.setText("Today");
                }

            }
        }


 int position;

    //TIMESTAMP
    private String getTimeDate() {

        final Post post = mPost.get(position);
        final String TAG = "";

        String difference = "";
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        //Date format
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

        //Today's date
        Date today = calendar.getTime();
        simpleDateFormat.format(today);

        Date timestamp;
        try {
            if (post.getTimestamp() != null) {
                timestamp = simpleDateFormat.parse(post.getTimestamp().toString());
                difference = String.valueOf(Math.round(((today.getTime() - timestamp.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24)));
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getTimeDate: ParseException: " + e.getMessage());
            difference = "0";
        }

        return difference;

    }
```

Comment: guess you use java 8 or higher, so do not use the deprecated date API. use `javax.time.*`

Comment: @Jens The code is right than? Can't figure out what's wrong with it...

Comment: Your date Format is wrong. Read the documentation how it should looks like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @Jens I changed it to this ```SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");``` and it's still coming out as **today** and not the timedifference. You mind showing me exactly what you mean?

Comment: If you read the documentation you wil see that `Mon Dec 16 23:07:19 GMT+01:00 2019` is not equals to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: @Jens so what you're saying is that I have to pick the correct letter number combination to get the date back like ```Mon Dec 16 23:07:19 GMT+01:00 2019```? Like ```"EEE, MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"``` for instance?

Comment: Anytime the catch block is called, it return a "0" which signifies today in your code.

Comment: @NomadMaker but I think I took care of that with the above ```holder``` right? I wrote an if statement saying if the difference ! equal to 0 than return that

Comment: I think the main problem is that you're returning a valid String, "0", if your function can't parse the date.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. (I know I have told you before, but for other readers.)

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for the advice man I'm reading about it now and yeah it does seem much smoother. Will try to write the method instead of the one I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing the last part for the `SimpleDateFormat` the **Locale.US**. That fixed the problem I was having.

`SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);`

Answer (score 1):

The correct format for datestring "Mon Dec 16 23:07:19 GMT+01:00 2019" is

EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Bro, I'm still getting this... ```ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Dec 15 21:04:05 GMT+01:00 2019"```

Comment: ```E/: getTimeDate: ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Dec 15 21:04:05 GMT+01:00 2019"``` this is what it says I'm not sure which line I'm looking at it but it doesn't say which line... does the above not tell you anything?

Comment: Try to parse timestamp like this simpleDateFormat.parse(Date(1576534039437).toString()) E.g. wrap timestamp with Date and then cast is to string

Comment: bro I got ittttt... thank you so much for your help!! have been working on this for weeks ``````SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);```  I was missing the Locale.US, idk why that's what worked but it comes back correct now